# Finding birth and marriage records for Grodno

Tags: birth-records, marriage-records, poland

We are searching for birth records for Wanda Anna Jurewicz born May 15 1920 in Grodno Poland. Now that could be the region of Grodno. She only states Grodno. Her father was Wincenty Jurewicz and mother was we think Aniela Polubinska. We would like to find their marriage records as well. Don’t know the year. Wanda had a sister Helena and we think 2 brothers.

Answer (score 1):

For Polish records, I'm a big fan of https://genealodzy.pl/changelang-eng.phtml (English version)

Searching there for Jurewicz born around 1920 gave about 10 hits, but searching for "Wanda Jurewicz" turned up empty. Maybe searching for the parents would work.